# XPages: Data Grid

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm new in Xpages and I need help about use Data Grid(DG) or Dojo Data Grid(DDG).  How can I use “filters” using a Read/Write/Input DDG/DG whitin an XPages Form?  Example:  I have input Field in Xpages Form(1)  NumberCase DateCase  and in the same Form(1) I have  DDG/DG whith field’s  Article (array field) combo box ArticleType (array field) text Location (array field) text  The field’s in the DDG/DG are included in to the same form (Form 1), then, How can I use “filters” using a Read/Write/Input DDG/DG within an XPages Form, to only return the data that the field NumberCase match within DDG/DG and not that of all documents?    Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Might check this post http://xcellerant.net/dojo-grids-in-xpages/

Has a lot of tutorials here also